# Equivalent of `std::iter::inspect` for method chains

Tags: debugging, rust, method-chaining

In rust, is it possible to inspect the intermediate values in a chain of method calls? The equivalent method [exists for iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect) so that the values produced may be inspected before being passed to the next iterator in the chain. Essentially, I'm looking for something like this:

```rust
impl<T> T {
    fn inspect(&self, f: impl Fn(&Self)) -> &Self {
        f(&self);
        &self
    }
}

// ...

object
    .a()
    .inspect(|x| println!("after a(): {:?}", x))
    .b()
    .inspect(|x| println!("after b(): {:?}", x))
    .c();
```

The purpose is to aid in debugging a long chain of function calls; currently the only solution is to break up the chain with an assignment to a variable, print the variable, and then continue on with the rest of the chain.

Does something like this exist? I believe the orphan rules would forbid one from implementing it themself in general.

Comment: Not an answer, just a hint - check https://lib.rs/crates/tap.

Comment: @Cerberus arguably this is better than the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a trait for this almost exactly like that:

```rust
trait Inspect {
    fn inspect(self, f: impl Fn(&Self)) -> Self;
}

impl<T> Inspect for T {
    fn inspect(self, f: impl Fn(&Self)) -> Self {
        f(&self);
        self
    }
}
```

I modified it a bit to pass `self` by value to make it more flexible. It will work with `&T`/`&mut T` and return `&T`/`&mut T`.

Test:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    fn a(&self) -> &Self {
        self
    }
    fn b(&self) -> &Self {
        self
    }
    fn c(&self) -> &Self {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo {}
        .a()
        .inspect(|x| println!("after a(): {:?}", x))
        .b()
        .inspect(|x| println!("after b(): {:?}", x))
        .c();
}
```

Output:

```
after a(): Foo
after b(): Foo
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39268b97bff25fcce9787b17f5d4954f)

---

Test for mutable value:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Foo {
    value: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn a(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        self.value += 1;
        self
    }
    fn b(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        self.value += 2;
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo::default()
        .a()
        .inspect(|x| println!("after a(): {:?}", x))
        .b()
        .inspect(|x| println!("after b(): {:?}", x));
}
```

Output:

```
after a(): Foo { value: 1 }
after b(): Foo { value: 3 }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd45ba318ed88a35f7c6695888715ce1)

Answer (score 1):

There's a crate for that: [`tap`](https://crates.io/crates/tap). It provides a [`Tap`](https://docs.rs/tap/latest/tap/trait.Tap.html) trait with a [`tap()`](https://docs.rs/tap/latest/tap/trait.Tap.html#method.tap) method as well as additional traits and methods for various things like mutable access, optionals and more.

Specifically for `Option` and `Result`, [they also have unstable `inspect() methods](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/91345).